# ASP.NET MVC Model validation not working on one of the controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have model validation for user register,login and update. However the model validation only works on login and register. The update function does not respond either
The model

```
namespace DDemo.Models
{
    public class SysUser

    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter User ID")]
        [Remote(action: "VerifyUserID", controller: "Account")]
        public string InvestorId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Password")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 5 characters or more")]
        public string InvestorPw { get; set; }

        [Compare("InvestorPw", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
        public string InvestorPw2 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Email")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; } //@ sign 

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Contact Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{8}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter 8 digit number")]
        public string Contact { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller

```
 [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UserUpdate(SysUser user)
       {
            
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
                return View("UserUpdate", user);
            }
            else
            {
                string update =
                   @"
                UPDATE Investor 
                  SET InvestorPw = ('SHA1', '{1}'), FullName = '(2)', Email = '{3}', Contact = '{4}'  
                  WHERE InvestorId = '{0}'";

                int result = DBUtl.ExecSQL(update, user.InvestorId, user.InvestorPw, user.FullName, user.Email, user.Contact);

                if (result == 1)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Account Updated";
                    TempData["MsgType"] = "success";
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = DBUtl.DB_Message;
                    TempData["MsgType"] = "danger";
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Users");
            }
       }
```

The view

```
@model SysUser

<form asp-controller="Account"
      asp-action="UserUpdate"
      method="post">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-0 col-sm-4">
            <h2>Update Your Account</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="InvestorId">User ID :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" asp-for="InvestorId" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />                             
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="InvestorId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="FullName">Full Name :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="Email">Email ID :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="InvestorPw">Password :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="password" asp-for="InvestorPw" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="InvestorPw" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="InvestorPw2">Confirm :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="password" asp-for="InvestorPw2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="InvestorPw2" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="Contact">Contact :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Contact" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span asp-validation-for="Contact" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

@if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="alert alert-@ViewData["MsgType"]">
            <text>@ViewData["Message"]</text>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0mXt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFEug.png)
As in the picture, model validation works with register but not with update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix a form tag of your view,  move  the end of form to below of a submit button and  add @Html.ValidationSummary()

```
<form asp-controller="Account"
      asp-action="UserUpdate"
      method="post">

@Html.ValidationSummary(true) 

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-0 col-sm-4">
            <h2>Update Your Account</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

........

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```